# copy files in python with progress bar

Tags: python, for-loop, shutil

I have a python script that copy  folders and files existing in a selected place.
This task work perfect, now i want to display a progress bar while copying.

I used **tqdm** package that display the progress bar in the console, and it work good but the problem is that it display the progress bar on each files and walk over the all the existing files each time .

example : having a folder  includes 128 files  it will display the progress bar 128 time like this

> 100%---------128/128 100%---------128/128

what i want is to display the progress bar 1 time for all files being copied.

## code:

```
i=0
j=0
z=0
for dirpath, dirnames, files in os.walk(src):           
    print(f'Found directory: {dirpath}')
    if len(dirnames)==0 and len(files)==0:
        print("this directory is empty")
        pass

    for  file in files:
        full_file_name = os.path.join(dirpath, file)

        if os.path.join(dirpath) == src:
            if file.endswith("pdf"):
                if not os.path.exists(dst2):
                    os.mkdir(dst2)
                else:
                    print("the path alredy exist")

                 shutil.copy(full_file_name, dst2)
                i+=1

            elif file.endswith("docx") or file.endswith("doc"):

                 shutil.copy(full_file_name, dst)
                j+=1

        elif os.path.join(dirpath)== src2:
            if file.endswith("pdf"):
                numfile = len(files)

# i think the for loop must not be in this part.
                for z in enumerate(tqdm(numfile)): 
                    sleep(.1)

                 shutil.copy(full_file_name, dst3)
                z+=1
```

Answer (score 1):

Just create one tkinter progressbar widget and pass values to it from for loop.
close window once progress completes instead of printing to a console

[Progressbar Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubhfY.png)

Code sample for updating progress bar with tkinter:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import Progressbar
import time
def progressbar(ProgressValue):  # Update Progress bar with a int/float/string Round 0-100 #
    ProgBar['value'] = ProgressValue; root.update()
root = Tk()
ProgBar = Progressbar(root, length=365, style='black.Horizontal.TProgressbar')
ProgBar.pack()

time.sleep(2)
progressbar('10') #Use this
time.sleep(2)
progressbar('50')
time.sleep(2)
progressbar('100')
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: and how to relate the update of the progress bar with the files being copied ?

Comment: root.overrideredirect(True) use this line to hide minimize maximize and close button on the title bar

Comment: just divide the for loop count (progressbar(number of files/100))

Comment: count total number of file of all 3 type, divide it by 100 and add it to progressbar everytime